# Can I sudo a command on behalf of another user?

Tags: password, sudo, users, su

I'm using drupal and Aegir. Aegir automates many tasks of site creation. Aegir has control of Apache, I'm logen in as root, and I want to restart the Apache server, but I want to do it on Aegirs behalf. Unfortunately I do not know the Aegir password, so basically I'm wondering how to sudo something as another user.

Answer (score 12):

```
sudo -u <username> <command>
```

sudo accepts a user parameter, which will run it as that user.

Alternatively, since you are root:

```
su <username> -c <command>
```

Answer (score 6):

`su aegir` is what you're looking for, assuming the username is `aegir`. `man su` will give you more info on the `su` command.

That user likely won't be able to actually restart Apache if it's running on port 80, unless specifically configured to be allowed to do so. By default, `root` is the only user that can bind a service to a low port number.

Comment: You don't need root if either your process or the httpd executable have the cap_net_bind_service capability. Something like `capsh --uid=<aegir_uid> --inh=cap_net_bind_service` or the setup described at http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/NonRootPortBinding should work.

Comment: @GeraldCombs very true indeed. Updated to qualify the restriction a little more generally.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do the following

`runuser -l <username> -c <command>`

e.g

`runuser -l  Aegir -c service httpd restart`

But if you are root you can just su to the user with out a password.

su -l Ageir

J

Answer (score 0):

You can run as user using -u. This will not open programs as you are "logged in" as that user, so you will have to specify the whole path.

Example

```
jupyter notebook
```

Becomes this, if the normal user is Ubuntu:

```
sudo -u ubuntu /home/ubuntu/.local/bin/jupyter notebook
```

Find the location of Jupyter:

```
which jupyter
#Result: /home/ubuntu/.local/bin/jupyter
```